# Align text to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I align the text to right. I have a container with expand and collapsing. I want to align the expand/collapse text to right. I don't want to use `float:right;`. Is there any other way we can achieve the same.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/2354/

Comment: @webkit: Actually its an icon there not text as of now. for fiddle purpose I put a text.

Comment: an icon that is a font-icon? inline image? background image?

Comment: @Shane Then this is a pointless question. You should show the code that you are having problems with, or recreate the same thing in new code. Changing an image to text changes a lot of things.

Comment: Don't ask questions about a different problem to the one you are having, it wastes people's time. Update your question to your actual problem. Put an icon in your fiddle and try to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: If it's an inline level element (such as an image) it will still work with `text-align:right` - http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/2357/

Comment: @Paulie_D Problem is we have no idea what they have done with it. This code isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your CSS?

```
text-align: right
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
.header{
    text-align:right;
}
```

This will work for you sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/2355/)

```
.container .header {
  background-color:#d3d3d3;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to give a margin for the text.

Comment: because if your width is not fix then it will create problem

Answer (score 0):

Add text-align to your header class

**CSS :**

```
.container .header {
  background-color:#d3d3d3;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:right;
}
```